# Angular 2 Interface definition in Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I am having issues trying to write a specific interface in angular 2 when including another interface definition in the interface. see below

**posting.ts**

```
interface Coordinate {
    lng: number;
    lat: number;
}

export interface Posting {
    title: string;
    thumbnailUrl:string;
    price: number;
    hasPrivateBedroom: boolean;
    hasPrivateWashroom: boolean;
    posterGender: string;
    roommateGender: string;
    coordinate: Coordinate;
}
```

interface used in **posting.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Posting } from './posting';

@Injectable()
export class PostingService {

  getPostings(filter?: object): Posting[] {
    return [
      {thumbnailUrl: "http://placehold.it/3500x1500", price: 1200, title: "Bachelor pad with a playboy", hasPrivateBedroom: true, hasPrivateWashroom: false, posterGender: "male", roommateGender: "male", coordinate: {lng: -79.36, lat: 43.65} },
      {thumbnailUrl: "http://placehold.it/3500x1500", price: 1200, title: "Bachelor pad with a playboy", hasPrivateBedroom: true, hasPrivateWashroom: false, posterGender: "male", roommateGender: "male", coordinate: {lng: -79.36, lat: 43.65} },
    ];
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

Below is the error I receive
[image: Compilation Error]

Comment: Have you tried `export interface Coordinate` ?

Comment: Yes I have. Doesn't solve it

Comment: Are you compiling your ts files to js files?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Could you post it as a plunker?

Comment: Your code works for me. http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/